# Is there a standard function or notation to represent $\sqrt{A^\dagger A}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

For a complex number, the standard notation for the magnitude (or modulus) is
$$
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\abs{\operatorname{abs}}
|\a| = \abs(\a) = \sqrt{\a^*\a}
$$
For a matrix, the notion of *magnitude* is better captured by a norm
$($e.g.$\:\|A\|_2)\:$ while the pipe-delimited notation customarily denotes
$$|A| = \det(A)$$
The few papers that I've read in Quantum Information Theory adopt the
$|A|$ notation.

I've also seen $\abs(A)$ used to denote either the elementwise `abs()` function or else the matrix function $\sqrt{A^2}.\:$ So I was wondering if there was some other unambiguous function or notation, otherwise I'll just stick with $\sqrt{A^\dagger A}$

Comment: The Wikipedia article on polar decomposition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) uses $|A|$. I think this is not very standard notation for the determinant so it's fine to use here although you should define it for clarity.

Comment: $|A|$ is already a popular notation for $\sqrt{A^\dagger A}$, although this notation, depending on context, also denotes the determinant as well as the entrywise absolute value of $A$.